# Power supply - Boost voltage over distances

Tags: ac, buck, boost, flyback, distance

I'm looking for a good power supply design to boost the DC voltage and convert it to AC so it can be transported over a long distances with low loss. I have drawed a example picture:

[image]

The only thing that I know at the moment is that the two batteries are delivering 24VDC, and the `load` needs 9VDC and draws 3.8A. I just discovered that I have drawn to small fuse on the 24VDC side (`1A`).

I'm free to choose both frequency and the voltage on the AC, my only goal is to deliver 3.8A@9VDC to the `load` over a distance up to 300 meters with smallest possible loss.

So the questions are:
- What frequency should I choose? I have read that higher frequency is equal to smaller devices?
- What voltage should I choose? 
- Which power supply design should I use? I have looked at `Boost-buck` designs, but they do not provide isolation. I have also looked at `flyback` supplies.

Comment: Try doing the calculations first, assuming average conversion losses, if those are really smaller than running the 12V over that short of a distance.

Comment: For sure not boosting to AC, rather to DC. Your boost/buck can operate at higher frequencies, but the boosted has to be rectified and filtered to DC.

Comment: 3.8A*9V=34.2W witout losses, then you want to convert 24VDC*1A=24W with losses and get 34W? Sorry, not possible.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič but does not AC provider lower loss? And yeah, I did wrong in my calculations when i drawn that example, I was thinking of 48VDC, but the batteries only deliver 24VDC. I corrected myself in the post.

Comment: @BufferOverflow No, high freq. AC is lossy. You would require twisted pair cable and you'd better go with lower voltage, because 480VAC is pretty dangerous. Some good boost converter would be a phase shifted PWM which outputs almost sine wave HF voltage, then you can rectify this on other side with schotky diodes and use a conventinal (if you lower the boost voltage) smps 85-280V to 9V.

Comment: @BufferOverflow Sorry a typo, you boost the voltage to 200 to 300VDC and then you use a conventinal SMPS. No need to use expensive PS-PWM and HF voltage with twisted cables.

Comment: @BufferOverflow Some cheap chinese junk: 1  http://www.ebay.com/itm/9V-3-8A-Aluminium-Switching-Power-Supply-LED-Driver-Transformer-35W-/201468475076?hash=item2ee874f6c4:g:52gAAOSwv-NWZlck

2:http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC12V-24-to-DC-200-450V-70W-high-voltage-converter-boost-step-up-power-supply-/152037359535?hash=item236621ffaf:g:qlwAAOSw~gRVrd-U

Comment: "...with **smallest possible** loss." - Why?

Comment: @BruceAbbott: Because the batteries are charged with solar energi, so I don't want to waste the power.

Comment: The solar panels are already wasting ~80% of the power hitting them. How much do you want to spend to save another few percent? The simplest and most reliable solution is to just use a cable thick enough to keep transmission losses down to an _acceptable_ level.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to build converters that have significantly greater than 90% conversion efficiency, especially when you have large conversion ratios (1:20 and 50:1, in this case). Therefore, even if you have no losses in the wire, you've already got an overall efficiency that's no greater than about 81%.

If you just transmit the 24 VDC across the 300 meters, and use a point-of-load converter to produce the 9V, the current in the long wire would be about 1.6 A. A 2-wire cable would have a total conductor length of 600 meters, and if we want to match the performance of the boost converter, it must drop no more than 2.4 V, which means that the total resistance can be no more than 1.5 Ω, or 2.5 mΩ/m. You would need to use AWG 8 wire (2 mΩ/m) in order to meet this requirement.

If you boost the voltage to 480 VDC, then the current in the wire is just 80 mA. AWG 18 wire (20.4 mΩ/m) would give you a voltage drop of about 1V (a loss of just 0.2%), so perhaps this voltage is overkill.

A voltage of 120 VDC would give you a current of 320 mA and a voltage drop of 4 V (3.3%) over that same AWG 18 wire, so perhaps this is a more reasonable value to use, giving you an overall efficiency on the order of 78%.

Comment: 78% efficiency sounds pretty good. What kind of power supply design do you recommend to boost voltage from 24VDC to 120VDC?

Comment: I'm almost wondering if a COTS inverter and a small off-line switcher are the best choice for his problem...